# Build MSI to install DLL and make it accessible from "Add References" in VS

Tags: .net, dll, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, managed

I'd like to build an MSI installer that installs a managed DLL and makes it accessible to users from Visual Studio's "Add References" menu in Solution Explorer. I believe I am supposed to add a key into the Windows registry but I cannot see how to tell the VS project for the MSI to do this at install.

How is this done and where should I look for tutorials on this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders
```

Add a subkey (the name of which doesn't matter, but might as well be descriptive) whose default value is the *folder* containing your assemblies, and you should be good to go.

**How to add the required key using WiX**

This is a stripped-down fragment of WiX code for creating the required key and setting its default value to the folder in which your assemblies were installed.  *This is not a complete WiX installer and cannot be pasted directly -- I have removed Guid attributes and shown only the Directory, Component and Feature declarations.*  Once you've seen some complete WiX code it should be reasonably clear how to merge these bits in.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <!-- Path from WiX file to the DLL(s) you're installing -->
  <?define BuildPath="..\Bin\Release" ?>
  <!-- The base key path - note no HKLM -->
  <?define AssemblyFolders = "Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders" ?>

  <Product>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="YourCompany">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Your Product">
            <!-- Id="AssemblyFolder" captures the location where the DLL gets installed -->
            <Directory Id="AssemblyFolder" Name="Bin">
              <Component Id="AssemblyComponent">
                <!-- This is the bit that copies the assembly file -->
                <File Id="YourDll.dll" Checksum="yes" Source="$(var.BuildPath)YourDll.dll" />
              </Component>
              <Component Id="ControlRegistrationComponent">
                <!-- This is the bit that creates the registry key -->
                <RegistryKey Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.AssemblyFolders)\Your Product Name">
                  <!-- Square brackets result in a reference -- so the install folder gets picked up -->
                  <RegistryValue Action="write" Value="[AssemblyFolder]" Type="string" />
                </RegistryKey>
              </Component>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="PRODUCTROOTFEATURE">
      <!-- This causes the assembly to be installed -->
      <ComponentRef Id="AssemblyComponent" />
      <!-- This causes the registry key to be created -->
      <ComponentRef Id="ControlRegistrationComponent" />
    </Feature>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

To build the MSI once you've got a full WiX script, you can use a batch file, the core of which looks like this:

```
candle.exe "%WXS_NAME%.wxs" -out "%WXS_NAME%.wixobj"
light.exe "%WXS_NAME%.wixobj" -out "%WXS_NAME%.msi"
```

where %WXS_NAME% is the name of the WiX .wxs source file.

(I realise this probably looks a bit cryptic but (a) there are lots of WiX samples, tutorials and reference material out there to help you get started and (b) the Votive add-in for Visual Studio may shield you from some of the guts anyway.)

To automatically build the MSI, use the Votive add-in (part of WiX), or a post-build step, or a MSBuild build script.  We use a build script because we usually want to build the MSI only as part of our automated build -- doing it in a post-build step would slow down development builds -- but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have edited the registry on the target machine, added the Microsoft, .NETFramework and AssemblyFolders to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE and then added a string in there with the installation location hardcoded in it (should I use an environment variable) but it still doesn't work: the DLL is not listed in Add References. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget you need to create a key (in regedit, a folder) *under* AssemblyFolders, and set the default value of that *subkey*.  Take a look at the registry on your machine to see examples.  And I'm a bit surprised you're having to create the base keys -- they should already be there (especially `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft`!).  Please don't take this the wrong way, but are you sure you're adding the keys in the right place?

Comment: Another location that contributes to the Add References dialog is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx`.

Comment: I see what you mean about the subkey from the registry on my machine but I also see that nothing is being added by my MSI at all. I created a "Setup project" from the MS template, went to its solution explorer, clicked the "Registry Editor" icon, browsed to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE but then it lists only "[Manufacturer]" and not "Microsoft". How am I supposed to get my MSI project to add registry keys? Also, shouldn't these registry keys be functions of the installed location and not hardcoded?

Comment: Re how to add registry keys: I can give you the answer in WiX, but I'm not familiar with VS Setup projects to help with those.  Sorry!  Re "shouldn't these [be] the installed location and not hardcoded" -- yes, they should.  Again, I don't know how VS Setup projects represent the installed location, but I'd be happy to provide WiX code for this if that would be useful.

Comment: The Setup project that Microsoft sells as part of VS seems to be crap. I'll take a look at WiX, thanks for the reference. How would you do this with WiX? Can I make it build an installer as a post-build part of the DLL?

Comment: Jon, I've edited the answer to include fragmentary WiX code, and added some basic info about your options for building the installer.  But WiX is a big topic: you'll probably need to read up a bit on WiX before it will make sense.  Good luck!